# optimizing setup and teardown for sample django model using django_nose and django-dynamic-fixture

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, nose, django-testing

Given my model is following:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I am using [django-dynamic-fixture](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture) to generate model fixtures easily for the test. I am also using [django_nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) which helps me run and manage tests pretty nicely.
Having setup the test_runner in settings.py file and putting all installables at place.

To generate a model as above the test should be

```
from django_dynamic_fixture import G


class BookModelTest(TestCase):

     def test_book_creation(self):
         author1 = G(Author)
         author2 = G(Author)
         book = G(Book, author=[author1])
         book_obj = Book.objects.all()
         self.assertEquals(book_obj.count(), 1)
         self.assertEquals(list(book_obj[0].author), [author1])
         self.assertEquals(book_obj[0].title, book.title)
         self.assertNotEquals(list(book_obj[0].author), [author1])

    def another_test(self):
       "Here as well i need the same, author1, author2 and book
```

Also if i write

```
class AuthorModelTest(TestCase):

   def test_some_stuff()
```

I would be needing some fixture value. 
So following are the queries i had:

How do i keep my fixture generation DRY. Meaning not creating book and author fixtures from `G` in each of the functions?

django_nose helps to optimize the setUp and tearDown methods and improves speed, how can I use them here? Just putting *django_nose.FastFixtureTestCase* will take care of setUp tearDown pains? Or do I need to use *TransactionTestCase*? How do I optimize the above fixture and test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TransactionTestCase` helps you save an saving an entire DB flush per test, it expects you to start with an unmarred db, you are free to generate it using any fixture generator. `TransactionTestCase` however leaves the database cluttered, django-nose helps you optimize it. django-nose however has another test runner `FastFixtureTestCase` helps you optimize the setUp and tearDown.

As already said, you can use any fixture generation, if you want the goodness of django-nose use the `FastFixtureTestCase` and it will help you optimize the IO time.

Comment: FastFixtureTestCase will not help if you are using django-dynamic-fixture. As authors says on https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose#how-fixture-bundling-works "For future tests, it is better to use the "model maker" pattern, creating DB objects programmatically. This way, tests avoid setup they don't need, and there is a clearer tie between a test and the exact state it requires. The fixture bundler is intended to make existing tests, which have already committed to fixtures, more tolerable."

Answer (score 4):

Latest version of [Django Dynamic Fixture](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture) includes a [Django Nose plugin](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture/wiki/Documentation#wiki-setup_nose_plugin) to facilitate creating global fixtures. Check if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

FastFixtureTestCase is used for fast fixtures handling and it will not help in this situation at all.

Using django_dynamic_fixture or factory_boy (which I use personally) and always creating only as little objects as it is needed for tests, and even if it is possible - completely omit database (e.g. when testing only model methods not related to other models) is the fastest approach.

Also if database is what is slowing you down try to use regular database for testing. I know that sqlite in tests should be fast, because it is run in-memory and all that stuff, but it is just still much slower than normal postgres/mysql database. You can also enable REUSE_DB option in django-nose which will make tests startup and shutdown much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with django-nose's optimization features, but in answer to your first question, if you repeatedly need the same set of objects for a bunch of tests, I'd just make a utility method or standalone function you can call that creates those objects and returns them (or one of them from which you can get to the others).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a data API handling data creation.

```
class TestData(objects):
    def create_a_book_with_author(self):
         author1 = G(Author)
         author2 = G(Author)
         book = G(Book, author=[author1])

class BookModelTest(TestCase):

     def setUp(self):
         TestData().create_a_book_with_author()
         self.book_obj = Book.objects.all()

     def test_book_creation(self):
         self.assertEquals(self.book_obj.count(), 1)
         self.assertEquals(list(self.book_obj[0].author), [author1])
         self.assertEquals(self.book_obj[0].title, book.title)
         self.assertNotEquals(list(self.book_obj[0].author), [author1])
```

Comment: your answer does not talk about `nose' stuff.